# N cards, choose 2, what is the probability card 1 comes before card 2.

Tags: probability, card-games

Initial example: Ace, Jack, and King. What is the probability the Ace will be drawn before the Jack?

Answer: 50/50

Reason: 6 possibilities (3!), 3 where Ace is drawn before, 3 where Ace is drawn after the Jack.

How to generalize this example for N cards? I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this. Is it always 50/50?

Comment: The problem is symmetric, the card label has no influence on the probability. The result is binary because there are only two outcomes, either card 1 before two or the other way.

Comment: It's not clear what generalization to $N$ cards should mean.   If you state the setup more clearly, it would help.  For example, are $N$ cards being drawn, or is it just two cards drawn from a deck of $N$ cards?  If the latter, it is possible neither Ace nor Jack might be drawn, and the trial would be inconclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the probability will always be $50$-$50$.  There's a $1$-$1$ correspondence between permutations where the Ace precedes the Jack and permutations where the Jack precedes the Ace, obtained by simply taking a given permutation and reversing the Jack and the Ace.  Moreover, those two possibilities exhaust all of the possible permutations.  So the Ace will always precede the Jack in exactly half of the possible permutations.